# Allocate Memory for Functions in com.sun.jna.Library (Functions from C# DLL)

Tags: java, c#, dll

Good day, Everyone!

This is my first time posting here, so I apologize in advance for the newbie mistakes in posting.

I am supposed to call a C# method in Java program. I am using RGiesecke.DllExport(1.2.7) to export my C# static method and com.sun.jna(4.2.2) to load the DLL in Java.

However, it always results to

```
Invalid memory access
java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:477)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invokeString(Function.java:658)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:402)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:323)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:236)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.Parse(Unknown Source)
```

I figured that it is caused by creating new C# objects in the called method because I have not yet allocated memory for the function.

I would like to confirm/ask if there is a way I can allocate memory for function in  `com.sun.jna.Library` (loaded C# DLL).

Shown are the codes below:

**Java (Interface for class):**

```
package com.example.mydllclass

import com.sun.jna.Library;

public interface IMyDllClass extends Library {

    String Parse(String path);
}
```

**Java (Loading dll and invoking method)**

```
public class MyClassProcess {

    private final String DLL_PATH = ".\\MyClass.dll"

    public String processFile(String path){

        IMyDllClass INSTANCE =(IMyDllClass)Native.loadLibrary(DLL_PATH,IMyDllClass.class);

        return INSTANCE.Parse(path);
    }
}
```

**C# Method**

```
public class MyDllClass{

    [DllExport("Parse", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static string Parse(string path)
    {
        String result = "";

        ProcessResultCalculator processResultCalculator = new ProcessResultCalculator(); // I need to create this
        result = processResultCalculator.execute(path);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings ... I'm pretty sure that JNA do not marshal java's `String` to `BSTR` ... so maybe first you should try to add right marshaling hint